# How to extract a substring from URL

Tags: ruby, regex, url

I need some help with RegEx. I have a URL:

```
../../temporary/12357704$002cXX$002c302036261/-1;jsessionid=13817F357AB3CD30E0836AA89903A003
```

or

```
../../temporary/12337704$002cXX$002c30222261/-1;jsessionid=13817F357AB3CD30E0836AA89903A003
```

I want always to extract the part between `'../../temporary/'` and `'$002..'` so it is `12357704` and `12337704`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
result = url.gsub(/^\.\.\/\.\.\/temporary\/(.*?)\$002.*/, "\\1")
```

This extracts anything after `'../../temporary/'` and before `'$002..'`. (Accomplished by `.*?`, which is "non-greedy").

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution:

```
str.scan(/^..\/..\/temporary\/(\d*)?\$002.*$/).flatten.first
```

where str is your url.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, but of course you'd need to be sure that the URL matches, or match will return null.

```
var result = your_url.match(/temporary\/([^$]*)/)[1];
```